# Invoking a program which uses GetForegroundWindow() over PSExec returns Idle

Tags: psexec, getforegroundwindow

For automation purposes, I need to know the foreground window process running on a remote machine.
I've written small scripts (`C#`, `Python`, `Powershell`) to do this - each of these scripts is using some or the other form of GetForegroundWindow()

These scripts work perfect if I run them on manually the machine.

But when I use PSExec to run these scripts from a remote machine, all of these return process name = Idle

What could have gone wrong?